# How to store parametrized listeners in list?

Tags: android

I have a listener:

```
public interface OnCompleteListener<T> {
    void onComplete(T data);
}
```

I store it in list:

```
private List<OnCompleteListener<?>> mListeners = new ArrayList<>();

// ...

public void addType1Listener() {
    addListener(new OnCompleteListener<Type1>() {
       //...
```

});
    }

public void addType2Listener() {
        addListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
           //...
});
    }

```
private <T> void addListener(OnCompleteListener<T> listener) {
    mListeners.add(listener);
}
```

I am trying to get it by this way:

```
public <T> OnRequestsCompleteListener<T> get(int i) {
    return (OnRequestsCompleteListener<T>) mListeners.get(i);
}
```

Type1 and Type2 have no parent class and cannot have.
But I get 'unchecked cast' warning. How to get it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying genetic T in a method, you need a class with generic T

```
public class ListenerCollection <T> {

    private List<OnCompleteListener<T>> mListeners = new ArrayList<OnCompleteListener<T>>();


    public void addListener(OnCompleteListener<T> listener) {
        mListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public OnCompleteListener<T> get(int i) {
        return mListeners.get(i);
    }
}
```

Suppose you have a class *OnRequestCompleteListener*, implemening `OnCompleteListener<String>`.  Then you do:

```
   ListenerCollection<String> lcollection;

   ...........

   OnRequestCompleteListener newListener = (OnRequestCompleteListener) lcollection.get(i);
```

That doesn't give any warning.

Comment: Sorry for inaccuracy. I can't specify type for a class and T can be different types. Please look updated question.